# Generating random samples from a probability distribution function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, matlab, sampling

I am trying to generate a random sample from the distribution (PDF) of the form $x^2 e^{-x^2}$. I am using MATLAB. One method suggested was to find the CDF and equate $CDF(x) = U$. Then solve for $x$ in terms of $U$ and set U to be a uniform distribution (MATLAB can easily sample using 'rand' function). Then $x$ forms the required distribution. However, I don't know how to integrate $x^2 e^{-x^2}$ to get the CDF. Alternatively, could you please suggest an alternative method in MATLAB if it exists.

Comment: I assume the density is supposed to be $\frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}x^2e^{-x^2}$ so that it integrates to $1$?

Comment: I managed to work out definite integrals in MATLAB and the prefactor looks right. I am now trying to see if I can use definite integration to work with the above technique

Comment: Do you by any chance know if I have a pdf of form $x^2 e^{-b x^2}$, what the normalization constant becomes